# how to create a keymap for vim that has a regex argument

Tags: key-bindings

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3926718/766570) pattern is very useful to me to get the count of a pattern in a vim file:

```
:%s/pattern//gn
```

How can I do a keymap so that I can simply invoke it + `pattern` while I'm in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mapping like this:

```
nnoremap  S  :%s///gn<LEFT><LEFT><LEFT><LEFT>
```

`<LEFT>` is the left arrow key which allows you to move your cursor in command line mode. This way you can press `S` + `pattern` and you are good to go.

Comment: Lol that's so hacky.. even with vim standards

Comment: The idea comes from [Damian's Conway](http://howivim.com/2016/damian-conway/). It does the job and works the same on every platform, I would say it's not that bad :)

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to ask the user to type the pattern with `<c-r>=input("What do you want to count?")<cr>`.

But I don't find this approach very ergonomic, I avoid using `input()` as much as possible.

Instead, I have another approach: I've defined a `Count` command. In the end, I type `:Cou<tab> <pattern><cr>`.

It could be defined with the one-liner:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range=% Count 
\  echo eval(join(map(getline(<line1>,<line2>), 'count(v:val, "<args>")'), '+'))
```

Or if you prefer to stick with `s//gn` ->

```
command! -nargs=1 -range=% Count keeppatterns <line1>,<line2>s/<args>//gn
```

<del>(I prefer the solution with `:echo` as it leaves the search register unchanged, and as such it doesn't change what's highlighted when `&hlsearch` is set)</del>

Comment: Could use `:keeppatterns` with your substitution to prevent the search register mutation.

Comment: @PeterRincker. Yes, you're right. The thing is I'm not completely used to it yet ^^'

Comment: @LucHermitte yeah, it is only available for 4 years :)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt. Exactly, It's much too recent ^^

Comment: More seriously, in my plugins I often struggle to stay compatible with older versions of vim. As such, there are a few things that haven't entered yet in my everyday vocabulary.